# Подскажите как обратиться к последнему, добавленному в базу данных, элементу?

Tags: python, sqlite

У меня есть таблица в базе там id, name, age, как можно обратиться последнему добавленному в эту таблицу id
Я использую sqlite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите получить последнюю добавленную запись, то следует написать такой запрос:

```
select id, name, age from table
where id = (select max(id) from table)
```

Comment: А как в переменную записать этот результат, потому он выдает <sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x000001AF225CAAB0>

Comment: Попробуйте так: c.execute('запрос') result = c.fetchall()

Comment: Спасибо, вы помогли

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы получить всю строку с максимальным `id`:

```
select * from table_name order by id desc limit 1;
```

---

В Python:

```
con = sql.connect('data_per.db')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("create table if not exists users(id integer primary key autoincrement, name varchar(100))")
cur.execute("insert into users(name) values ('john'), ('max')")
con.commit()
```

чтобы получить максимальный `id`:

```
cur.execute('SELECT MAX(id) FROM users') 
row = cur.fetchone()
max_i = row[0]
print(max_i)
# 2
```

чтобы получить всю строку с максимальным `id`:

```
cur.execute("""select * from users order by id desc limit 1""")
row = cur.fetchone()
print(row)
# (2, 'max')
```

Comment: Так он выведет первого добавленного а не последнего

Comment: @Tesla, только что проверил у себя - выдает последний `id`. Может у вас только одна строка в таблице?

Answer (score 1):

Получить максимальный `id`:

```
SELECT MAX(`id`) FROM table_name;
```

Comment: `con = sql.connect('data_per.db')
cur = con.cursor()
max_i = cur.execute('SELECT MAX(`id`) FROM users;')
print(max_i)`
Выводит вот это <sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x000001A45248AB20>